# If the susanoo is pure chakra armor, could it be created independently by a non-uchiha shinobi?

Tags: naruto

I have this doubt.
Why couldn't/didn't anyone try to create a susanoo like chakra armor instead of simple cloaks when it was possible to manipulate chakra flow?

The raikage use lightning chakra cloaks and few others can use chakra mode cloaks to enhance their capabilities. Even taijiutsu users like Shira of the sand covered chakra around his body to create soundless movements. Hyuga clan members could release chakra  from their body effectively and use it as an extension of their body(like neji did to cover his blind spot). When naruto initially defeated kurama and took only his chakra, he could form hands from his kurama chakra mode. Shinobi could also shape and direct their chakra like rasengan and twin lion fists or even form chakra threads for controlling objects. So, if somebody could effectively   spread chakra around their body and control it like a puppet or something they could form a susanoo without being an uchiha.

Is it impossible or did nobody think of doing something like that?

Comment: There are other various charka armors throughout the series, and (if I’m not mistaken) it was explicitly stated that Susanoo was a unique ability to the Mangekyo Sharingan

Answer (score 0):

Out of universe answer:

Naruto power system isn't really made clear, Jutsu and abilities are mostly whatever the author wants and we aren't even explained how they work a lot of times (or even in cases like the reanimation Justu, where the infinite chakra even comes from, or how the jutsu is even possible). Susanoo was said to be something Mangkeyo Sharingan can do, and that's how it is really. Perhaps what you say could also be a thing if the author wants to do, though considering it's associated with Mangkeyo Sharingan, it'd kinda cheapen the uniqueness of the eyes.

In-universe answer:

Chakra armors are a thing in Naruto as you say, Naruto himself uses the chakra cloak and later on his transformation can rival Susanoo.

Asura could use something called Asura-mode (I hear it's in the manga, so it's canon, though I am not sure on that or how much about it is explained) which rivaled the Susanoo, it's a kind of chakra armor like you described which looks like the Kurama-mode Naruto uses.

So, it's possible to do something similar to Susanoo and it's been done by Asura (assuming it's canon).

Now as to whether you could imitate something exactly like Susanoo, it's arguable, the eyes might have some special stuff in them that allow that, and it might not really be like a traditional chakra armor.